# Automating tests to check XML output

Tags: java, xml, xsd, automated-tests

**Current situation:** 
Our software (back-end written in Java) has functionality to generate an XML file that includes data stored in the system. To paint a better picture, the file returns staff data such as their personal details, qualifications, medical conditions and availability to work.

However, there isn't a standard file structure that returns everything. What is returned depends on the company type, the time of the year and certain data stored against a member of staff. For example, if the company is a private limited company then medical conditions are not returned, qualifications are returned only during the winter months, availability to work data is only return if the member of staff is of a certain age, etc. This makes testing challenging as there are many scenarios to test to ensure the XML file is correct under different circumstances.

Changes to the structure of the XML are driven by the third party software that uses these files, and these seem to happen around every quarter each year. At the moment, the testing is not automated at all and we find ourselves doing a lot of manual testing. Each time there is a change we:

- Generate the test data through the UI
- Generate the XML file
- Check that the structure of the XML file is correct
- Check that the data returned in the XML file is correct
- Repeat above for the different scenarios for each company type

**Aim:** 
Ideally we want to be able to automate most (or at least some) of the testing, the structure of the XML changes frequently and testing it is time consuming.

Although the third party provides an XSD, using this to verify the XML structure is difficult because of the nature of the export and limitations of XSDs. The data export varies depending on certain data returned and XSDs do not have a way of saying "if this…return this data…otherwise return nothing".

Unit testing individual export methods is work in progress and part of a longer term goal. To properly write the unit tests, we have to refactor (a lot of) the code, which we are struggling for time with currently. However, we are attempting this for any new development.

We are looking to do some improvements short-term. I was thinking of writing some database scripts that would input data I need for the different company types, this data would be created on a separate, test schema where previous data is cleared down each time. Reason being, is that the script would include date variables, so that each year I'm running these tests I will always get a member of staff with date of birth that will trigger the data to be exported. Once an export is created, this is compared with the example file structure provided by the third party documentation. Of course, manual testing will always have to be done for new changes.

Does this approach sound reasonable? Are there any alternatives to doing this?

Comment: Handling xml (generation, parsing, extracting data) would be easier if you use groovy. Check the documentation - http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

I think your aproach is fine! I can suggest you tools to automate some steps described using only java:

> - Generate the test data through the UI

You can use tools like [dbunit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) to extract the scenario created using the UI. You can clear the Database and insert the data using java!

> - Generate the XML file
> - Check that the structure of the XML file is correct
> - Check that the data returned in the XML file is correct
> - Repeat above for the different scenarios for each company type

I think all this steps can be done in Junit too.

In Junit, could be something like this:

```
class XmlSpecification {

    @Before
    void setup() {
        // You have to implement for your specific database 
        this.clearDatabase()
    }

    @Test
    void forCompanyABCTheXmlShouldBeLikeThis() {
        // This method would use some dbunit api to insert data to the
        // db
        this.loadScenarioFor("company_abc_data.xml")
        // Then you get the xml, validate the format and the data and etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. In your experience of using a tool like dbunit, what benefits does it offer over plugging the data in and clearing it down with SQL scripts?

Comment: I've experienced two benefits. First, an easy integration with java code. We created some DBUtils class where we save, update or clear the whole database or some specifics tables, so it's easy to update the data xml. Another benefit is db agnostic. We needed tests running on Oracle DBs and Postgres. But if you already automated your code with your sql scripts, I don't see why the need to change to dbunit. I would keep it that way!